# My lowercase table names not working on the server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created a laravel blog locally on my system , i am in a windows environment. Now when i upload my files to the live server , i get the following error:

[image]

In my local environment i have my table names in lowercase , so as of now the error is saying the following:

```
'peckinga_blog.Admin' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `Admin` order by `created_at` desc limit 10)
```

The thing is my table name is actually peckinga_blog.admin not peckinga_blog.Admin as the error says. So how do i get laravel to look for the lowercase table name ??

**P.S.** :- I have temporaryly enabled the folllowing:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

In my `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data
>   directory.  Each table within a database corresponds to at least one
>   file within the database directory. Consequently, the case sensitivity
>   of the underlying operating system  plays a part in the case
>   sensitivity of database and table names.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing some operations on models then you can specify table name inside them like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'my_flights';
}
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#defining-models)